# Is it possible to check if a hyperlink works in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of hyperlinks in Column A. Some work, some don't. I'm looking to make a script that checks if they work, then removes the ones that don't. What I have is:

```
Sub UndoLink()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim n As String
i = 2
While i <= 4730

Set rng = Range("A" & i)
n = Range("A" & i).Value
    If Worksheet.Function.FileExist(rng) = False Then
        rng.Hyperlinks.Delete
        i = i + 1
    Else: i = i + 1
    End If
Wend
End Sub

Public Function FileExist(path As String) As Boolean
    If Dir(path) <> vbNullString Then FileExist = True
End Function
```

I'm getting a function error when I refer to FileExist in the sub. To clarify, the hyperlinks are all within strings like "648242," underlined in blue. If the path doesn't exist, I want to remove the hyperlink and keep the string. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove hyperlink:

```
rng.Hyperlinks.Delete
```

Comment: Awesome. That's the line I'm missing. What's the correct way to refer to a user-defined function in a sub?

Comment: Like `MyVar = MyFunction(param)`?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm getting an Object not defined error on the `If` statement. Is there something wrong with that line?

Comment: I recommend this way to check if file doesn't exist: `If Dir(rng) = "" Then ...`

Comment: This is giving me a type mismatch too. Rng is coming up as being equal to the value in that range, rather than its hyperlink.